# Show design view of rdlc report in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, rdlc

I wrote a program by visual studio 2008. then I installed v.2013 .
But it's not show design view of RDLC reports. I just see html codes.
some thing were wrong. when I want to add new connection (that it is in sqlserver 2008 R2) it's show error:

> Unable to add data connection. Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Sqlserver.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of it's
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

And I made setup , but now it's can't show. I'm be crazy everything is cluttered when I upgraded visual studio from 2008 to 2013.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade Microsoft Viewer:

- install SQLSysClrTypes
- install report Viewer 2012 runtime

Both are available from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747